# Do not cache footer

Tags: magento-1, footer, block-cache

I added this code in local.xml

```
<default>
    <reference name="footer">
         <action method="unsetData"><key>cache_lifetime</key></action>
         <action method="unsetData"><key>cache_tags</key></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

But it didn't work.
How can I refresh cache for `footer.phtml` programatically?

Comment: do you have full page cache enabled or it only the block cache?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74376/removing-a-template-from-the-cache/74377

Answer (score 6):

Sanjana, you can do this two ways:

### Disable with `getChildHtml()`

According to Magento's `getChildHtml()` you can tell it to use the cache or not to by sending the second parameter:

```
public function getChildHtml($name = '', $useCache = true, $sorted = false)
```

Set `$useCache` for this block when calling `$this->getChildHtml('footer')`: `$this->getChildHtml('footer', false)` in

- `1column.phtml`
- `2columns-left.phtml`
- `2columns-left.phtml` and
- `3columns.phtml`

which are root template files.

### By setting the cache lifetime to null in `layout.xml` and  create helper

Let's use a simple helper:

class My_Module_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {

```
public function returnNull() 
{
    return null;
}
```

}

**And set the value in layout xml like this:**

```
<reference name="footer">
    <action method="setCacheLifetime"><lifetime helper="mymodule/returnNull" /></action> </reference>
```

All thanks to [Fabrizio Branca](http://fbrnc.net/blog/2015/06/cache-and-layout-xml-tricks)

Comment: Hi Amit.. Where i need to add this line. public function getChildHtml($name = '', $useCache = true, $sorted = false)

Comment: Already explained it. in root layout file 1column.phtml

Comment: These solutions didn't work for my site.

Comment: Is there any other solution for this.. I m stuck with this issue since last two days. thanks in advance

Comment: Third option - add `public function getCacheLifetime() { return null; }` to the footer block. **This is only a good option if you already have a local override.** If you don't, go with one of those other two options.

Comment: First XML update will not work.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing is the same that Fabrizio explains here:

http://fbrnc.net/blog/2015/06/cache-and-layout-xml-tricks

To paraphrase his blog post, when you are setting the cache lifetime in the xml any of the values that you pass into the node `<action method="setCacheLifetime">` will evaluate to `true`. Even if you pass `null`, that will be converted to a `string`, and that `string` will be `true`. What you have to do is create a helper class that can set the value of null in the node.

Create a blank module and add your config file:

> {{site_root}}/app/code/local/{{your_namespace}}/CacheNull/ect/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <{{your_namespace}}_CacheNull>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </{{your_namespace}}_CacheNull>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <customcachenull>
                <class>{{your_namespace}}_CacheNull_Helper</class>
            </customcachenull>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Then create your helper class:

> {{site_root}}/app/code/local/{{your_namespace}}/CacheNull/Helper/Data.php

```
class {{your_namespace}}_CacheNull_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function returnNull()
    {
        return null;
    } 
}
```

Once you verify that the module is loading correctly on your site, you can add in the needed xml to remove the footer from the cache:

> {{site_root}}/app/design/frontend/{{you_theme_namespace}}/{{your_theme}}/layout/local.xml

```
<reference name="footer">
    <action method="setCacheLifetime"><lifetime helper="customcachenull/returnNull" /></action>
</reference>
```

To check if the footer is in fact not being cached, take another tool from Fabrizio:

https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_TemplateHints

Using this you will be able to see in full color what blocks are being cached as well as a bunch of other useful info about your site's content.

Answer (score 0):

The last step may need to be modified:

```
<reference name="footer">
    <action method="setCacheLifetime"></action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Working

- set `null` via helper

  ```
  <reference name="footer">
      <action method="setCacheLifetime">
          <value helper="helper/method" />
      </action>
  </reference>
  ```
- pass no argument

  ```
  <reference name="footer">
      <action method="setCacheLifetime"></action>
  </reference>
  ```
- use JSON data

  ```
  <action method="setCacheLifetime" json="value">
      <value>null</value>
  </action>
  ```

#### Not working:

- set `null` as string

  ```
  <reference name="footer">
      <action method="setCacheLifetime">
          <value>null</value>
      </action>
  </reference>
  ```
- empty value

  ```
  <reference name="footer">
      <action method="setCacheLifetime">
          <value></value>
      </action>
  </reference>
  ```

---

*Source: [http://fbrnc.net/blog/2015/06/cache-and-layout-xml-tricks](http://fbrnc.net/blog/2015/06/cache-and-layout-xml-tricks_)*