# removing a template from the cache

Tags: magento-enterprise, layout, cache, full-page-cache, block-cache

I'm getting a template via:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('ajaxCart'); ?>
```

and the block is declared like this:

```
<block type="page/html_topmenu" name="ajaxCart" as="ajaxCart" template="page/html/ajaxCart.phtml"/>
```

How can I remove this from our caching system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the full page cache of Magento Enterprise, you need to do two things:

1. disable block caching for the block
2. exclude the block from otherwise cached pages with full page cache hole punching

#### 1. Disable block caching

Change the block declaration to:

```
<block type="page/html_topmenu" name="ajaxCart" as="ajaxCart" template="page/html/ajaxCart.phtml">
    <action method="setCacheLifetime"></action>
</block>
```

This calls `setCacheLifetime(null)` and thus disables caching for the block.

More info about `setCachelifetime()` and how to use it in layout XML can be found here: http://fbrnc.net/blog/2015/06/cache-and-layout-xml-tricks

#### 2. Hole punching

create a module with a `etc/cache.xml` file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <placeholders>
        <ajax_cart_cache>
            <block>page/html_topmeu</block>
            <name>ajaxCart</name>
            <placeholder>AJAX_CART</placeholder>
            <container>Your_Module_Model_Container_Ajaxcart</container>
            <cache_lifetime></cache_lifetime>
        </ajax_cart_cache>
    </placeholders>
</config>
```

and the container model like this:

```
class Your_Module_Model_Container_Ajaxcart extends Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_Abstract
{
    protected function _renderBlock()
    {
        $blockClass = $this->_placeholder->getAttribute('block');
        $template = $this->_placeholder->getAttribute('template');

        $block = new $blockClass;
        $block->setTemplate($template);
        return $block->toHtml();
    }
}
```

Comment: the block is still cached.

Comment: Are you talking about full page cache or block cache?

Comment: i'm using full page cache.

Comment: OK the answer applies only to block cache, will update it

Comment: Okay I put everything within the page module.  However, when I revisit the same page again the block is no longer displayed on the page.

Comment: Then the block probably relies on data that is not present when the page is loaded from cache. You will need to create a more sophisticated container. Please refer to http://www.techytalk.info/hole-punching-with-magento-enterprise-edition-full-page-cache/ for detailed explanation

Comment: Seems to work pretty well, is there a reason behind ajax_cart_cache  tag naming?

Comment: This tag can have any name as long as it is unique in your installation.