# Magento Footer Behavior

Tags: cache, footer, magento-community

I just notice that when ever I add this codes on the Magento Footer:

```
$current_id = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
echo $current_id;
```

The Category ID is not changing whenever I change the Category.
It only changes when I clear the cache.

It is possible that the Magento Footer is a Static One?
Cause I won't update unless you clear any cache.

Comment: try this link it might be help you http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63259/do-not-cache-footer

Comment: Follow @AkhileshPatel Link or use that code in cms page(add phtml call ont that cms page)

Comment: @AkhileshPatel It works. Thanks. You should have answered it so I can up vote it.

Comment: Added my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the cache lifetime value from XML

```
<reference name="footer">
    <action method="setCacheLifetime"><s>null</s></action>
</reference>
```

or

```
<reference name="footer">
    <action method="setCacheLifetime" />
</reference>
```