# In footer.phtml file php code is not working properly

Tags: magento-1.9, footer

Strange in magento footer.phtml file. I am adding a below code in footer area to place text according to current page, whether its cms page or any other page but it is not working correctly.

```
if(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms')
{
  echo "CMS page";
}
else{
    echo "Not a CMS page";
}
```

But its not working, while this code is working fine in header.phtml file provide the correct result according to page.

If I click "Flush Magento Cache" button from "Cache Storage Management" section in back-end it will work for fist time but when I change page to product or vice versa its will not works, it provide the same result all time.

Also header.phtml file code work correctly all time.

Please can anyone suggest me on this?

Comment: what error you getting ? the code which you using is correct, cache problem i think

Comment: Please share your footer XML code and footer.phtml file full code.

Comment: In footer.phtml I am adding this code at the top area and I have not made any changes in xml file. Also sorry where I can get xml code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
if(Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage()) {
    echo 'You are in Homepage!';
} else {
    echo 'You are NOT in Homepage!';
}
```

Comment: I tried this code but it will also give same result always. I need to  click "Flush Magento Cache" button from "Cache Storage Management" section in back-end only then It will change result but after that it will again show same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
if(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms')
{
  echo "CMS page";
}
else{
    echo "Not a CMS page";
}
```

instead of

```
if(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms')
{
  echo "CMS page";
}
else{
    echo "Not a CMS page";
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Not works, this also print the same result always, After flush cache it change result to correct one but again give same result..

Comment: Are you using full page cache?

Comment: Sorry, What is full page cache. If its extension then we are not using any extension to increase  page speed

Comment: I am not asking you to add new extension. This type of issues are generally occurs due to FPC extension.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this issue, you have to make footer block as noncacheable for cms pages

At layout files, add below code

```
<default>
<reference name="footer">
    <action method="setCacheLifetime">null</action>
</reference>
</default>
```

**or**

```
<default>
<reference name="footer">
    <action method="setCacheLifetime" />
</reference>
</default>
```

You can help from

[Do not cache footer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63259/do-not-cache-footer)

http://fbrnc.net/blog/2015/06/cache-and-layout-xml-tricks

Comment: I have added these codes in local.xml file but not works. Might be local.xml files code not works. Not sure. 

Also When I disable "Blocks HTML output" in "Cache Storage Management" section in magento backend my footer.phtml code is working fine.